# Is the Azure Function VS extension opensource?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I'm looking around for the Azure Function VS extension source. Is this published?
I'd like to point the extension at a private build of some of the host and templates for developer testing. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The VS extension itself is not open source but when it comes to running your functions the extension uses the [azure-functions-core-tools](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools) which are open source.

So if you want to run a customized version of the functions host then you can do this fairly easily by making a build of core tools that includes your custom host. You could run then run that from the command line or you could create a custom launch profile in VS so that when you F5 your function project it runs your build of the core tools. Something like this:

[image]